# How to select distinct mongodb database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, php-mongodb

I am very new to using mongodb via Codeigniter. I have noticed some active records for Mongodb is very similar to the sql for instance

```
$this->db->get('mytable');
$this->mongo_db->get('mytable');
```

However I ran into a problem where the distinct does not work:

```
$this->mongo_db->distinct('name');
$this->mongo_db->get('mytable');
```

Been searching around for this but couldn't find anything, is there a way for this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I working with this library for CodeIgniter (https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library), and there exists the method: switch_db($db_name);

Then with the get you can choose witch collection (in MongoDB tables are collections), like you did in your example:

$this->mongo_db->get('collection_name');

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$this->mongo_db->distinct('collection', 'field_name');
```

It will help you to find distict value from collection.
make sure you have installed mongo_db library.